# Meaning of "No instanceType" in AWS cost explorer report

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

Could someone help me in understanding the meaning of "No instance type"  in the AWS Cost explorer report?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the mining of `***` - it should have explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will be charged for "no instance type" when you have terminated the EC2 instance but the resources related with that instance is not deleted/cleaned up like

- Elastic IP addresses
- Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) volumes **etc..**

Check if there are unused resources related to any previous instances that you created and terminated.

You could follow the steps mentioned in the article to clean up the common resources [Here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-billing-terminated/)

Answer (score 5):

All the answers above are correct but for each one individually, and thus you see the different **"in my case it was ..."**

The general answer is "No Instance Type" charge is for all the services that are not running on ec2 instances. In order to understand which one are those you can simply explore by setting side bar filter in cost explorer for "Instance Type" to "No Instance Type" option and now group by "Service" or "Usage Type" to understand what you are being charged for. By doing that you can find out that those services can be lambdas, network, sqs, taxes etc...

Answer (score 2):

In my case the "no instance type" was mostly data transfer out, I mapped that grouping by usage type.

[image: Cost Explorer graph]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was Taxes. I had grouped by "Instance type", but when I switched the grouping to "Services", that peak on the graph below (on the 31st of August) turned out to be just taxes.
[image]